# How to send Facebook message from Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook, actionscript

So I can get online friends without problems into my Flash, but how can I send them a message to Facebook chat? Is there any API for that? I found some applications that are doing this. Can anybody point me somwehere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an XMPP Library (try http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/xiff/ ), and read carefully this page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/
Which describe what the Facebook chat support.